# Detect div or txt array in class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have array `['.top-menu','txt.name a']`

**.top-menu** = This is div,i want change background color;

**.name a** = This is text, i want change color text;

http://jsfiddle.net/9z5du/1521/

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask]. Questions should be self contained and include the relevant code. Demos are great but should only be used to support what actually exists in the question. We shouldn't need to go off site to review what your issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the global `bg` variable as local in `each()` scope:

```js
var ids = ['.top-menu', 'txt.name a'];
var clbg = '';

$.each(ids, function(index, value) {
  var bg;
  if (value.indexOf('txt') > -1) {
    value = value.replace("txt", "");
    bg = 'color';
  } else {
    bg = 'background-color';
  }

  $(value)
    .mouseover(function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      $(value).css(bg, 'green');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top-menu">This is div, we will change background-color</div>

<div class="name">
  <a href="#">This is text, we will change color</a>
</div>
```

I think you can also use just `CSS`:

```css
.top-menu:hover{
  background-color: green;
}
.name a:hover{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu">This is div, we will change background-color</div>
<div class="name">
  <a href="#">This is text, we will change color</a>
</div>
```

Also, if you need a hover effect you can use `jQuery`'s `hover()` method:

```js
var ids = ['.top-menu', 'txt.name a'];
var clbg = '';

$.each(ids, function(index, value) {
  var bg;
  if (value.indexOf('txt') > -1) {
    value = value.replace("txt", "");
    bg = 'color';
  } else {
    bg = 'background-color';
  }

  $(value).hover(
    function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      $(value).css(bg, 'green');
    }, function() {
      $(value).css(bg, '');
    }
  );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top-menu">This is div, we will change background-color</div>

<div class="name">
  <a href="#">This is text, we will change color</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

bg is global. So it will have the vaue of the last iterated elems value. You need to make it local to the function:

```
var ids = ['.top-menu','txt.name a'];
var clbg = '';

 $.each(ids, function(index, value) {

 if (value.indexOf('txt') > -1)
 {
 value = value.replace("txt", "");
 var bg = 'color';//var to make it local
 }
 else
 {
 var bg = 'background-color';//if bg is global, it will be background-color for all elems, you need var to make it local
 }

$(value).mouseover(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
$(value).css(bg,'green');
 });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekddev4h/

By the way, much shorter:

```
[[".top-menu","color"],["txt.name a","background-color"].map(el=>document.querySelector(el[0])).forEach(el=>el[0].onmouseover=function(){this.style[el[1]="green";});
```